# What happens to user process when the kernel crashes?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm analyzing a kernel dump crash.
I want to know in this case when the kernel fail and all the system go down, if it sends SIGTERM to all process or what happen ?

Comment: How should it do that? It crashed... And even if, what should a user process do without a kernel?

Comment: And in case of file system corruption what the kernel should do

Comment: Well, the file access attempts will fail and produce an error, that's it. It is up to the user process to handle that error.